# Не собирается проект GoLang. package BeatsPro/internal is not in GOROOT

Tags: golang

я только начинаю изучать Go и у меня возникла проблема при сборке проекта.
Сначала писал проект на винде, там все было ок, потом залил на github и перешел на ubuntu, клонировал репозиторий и установил go

При попытке собрать проект падает ошибка

```
 main.go:4:2: package BeatsPro/internal is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/BeatsPro/internal)
    main.go:5:2: package BeatsPro/internal/configs is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/BeatsPro/internal/configs)
    main.go:6:2: no required module provides package github.com/joho/godotenv: working directory is not part of a module
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот переменные go которые я прописал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект находится в папке **/home/daniil/go/src** как и указано в GOPATH, но он почему-то пытается найти его в директории GOROOT.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: скорее всего у вас в настройках IDE прописано "включить инткграцию как go modul проекта". откройте настройки IDE -> go -> go module -> enable go modules integration.  включена?

Comment: а из обычной консоли билдится ?

Comment: из обычной консоли - точно такая-же проблема

Comment: Сделал go mod init в корневом каталоге проекта и включил enable go modules integration. Все завелось, только я не до конца понимаю почему